# Send keyboard/mouse inputs with python macro keep target window background

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto, pyautogui

I'm trying to make a macro program with python 3.7 on Windows10

I want to send keyboard/mouse inputs to any specific target window while the target window keep inactivated(minimized or background)

pyautogui seems to not be able to do that (If I miss something let me know plz)

pywinauto can send inputs to specific target window but it always make the target window activate.

Is there any way keeping target window inactivated????

```py
import pywinauto

app = pywinauto.application.Application().connect(best_match='123 - Notepad', top_level_only=False, visible_only=False)

form = app.window(title_re='123 - Notepad')

for i in range(1, 10):
    form.type_keys("12e12e21e")
```

Comment: There is no specific way to utilize the mouse inputs while the keyboard is minimized however, the link that @VisalyRyabov has provided should give you enough information on how to navigate the minimized window via sending key commands. Make sure you're using `send_keys()` or `set_edit_text()` *without* using `set_focus()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Remote Execution Guide -> Tricks to run automation on a locked machine](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html#tricks-to-run-automation-on-a-locked-machine)

Comment: Linked document is really helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer!!!!

```
app = Application(backend="win32").connect(process=12345)
form = app.window(title_re="windowtitle")
form.send_keystrokes("1234567")
```